# Azure Cloud Service Deployment: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-roles

I configured an MVC4 Web Role on my Azure Project. Locally (on the emulator) it works fine. I keep getting this error at runtime:

> The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I've tried:

- Adding the System.Web.Helpers DLL directly into the BIN Folder
- Referencing the Assembly on the project and setting CopyLocal=true
- Connected to remote desktop on the azure cloud service and installed MVC on the server to see if that was the issue. It still persists.

Comment: have you confirmed that the helper dll was copied?

Comment: Yes, I download the drop as a ZIP from TFS and confirmed it was inside the uploaded package. I also confirmed is was deployed to my site's bin folder by connecting with remote desktop to the Cloud Service Virtual Machine

Comment: what config file are you deploying?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand that one. I'm using a debug deployment on the staging server of my azure cloud service if that's what you're asking

Comment: kind of. can you share the config file you are deploying? is it web.config? if not, is it any different? does it make reference to every assembly referenced in your web.config?

Comment: Here is my complete web.config (with sensitive info stripped out)
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9764/WebConfig.txt

Comment: this looks perfect. are you deploying this web.config? or a different config file?

Comment: I have a web.config transform setup to change the connection strings at build time. But that's it

Comment: @DaveA thanks for the help. Found an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I ended up deleting the reference to System.Web.Helpers and installing the nuget Package Microsoft-Web-Helpers.

This solved the problem.

Comment: good problem solving. Azure is a surprisingly challenging platform to deploy to.

Comment: you can alternatively add all your dependencies (including Microsoft libraries) to a bin folder and add a reference to them from your project instead of referencing GAC or Package dlls.